# Setting ScrollBar bar size?

Tags: c#, silverlight, scrollbar

I'm creating a scrollbar in codebehind like so:

```
     ScrollBar b = new ScrollBar();
     Grid ScrollbarGrid = GetTemplateChild( "ScrollbarGrid" ) as Grid;
     b.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal;
     ScrollbarGrid.Children.Add(b);
```

What I need is for the scrollbar handle to be of a size I set myself if that is at all possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ViewportSize

like b.ViewportSize = 5;

take a look at [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.scrollbar.viewportsize%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) for more information.

and MSDN's [Track Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.track%28VS.90%29.aspx) how thumb size calculates

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Height and Width property of the scroll bar, is this what you need ?

Comment: No I need to set the size of that bar you can darg in the middle. The width/height properties affect the entire scrollbar...